# Can Racket macros take keyword arguments?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket, keyword-argument

I'd like to create a syntactic form in Racket that can accept a keyword argument, the way some functions can.

Having reduced it to a simple example, I tried writing:

```
(define-syntax sum-of-products
  (syntax-rules (#:extra)
    [(sum-of-products ([a b] ...))
     (+ (* a b) ...)]
    [(sum-of-products ([a b] ...) #:extra extra)
     (+ extra (* a b) ...)]))
```

Such that the following would then work:

```
(sum-of-products ([2 2] [3 3])) → 13
(sum-of-products ([2 2] [3 3]) #:extra 5) → 18
```

Unfortunately, Racket calls this "bad syntax", so obviously that attempt wasn't correct.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Keywords in syntactic patterns are treated the same as literals like numbers etc, so you don't need to specify them as keywords.  (That's needed *only* for identifiers.)  So the following works (note that I fixed the typo you had in the second example):

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax sum-of-products
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(sum-of-products ([a b] ...))
     (+ (* a b) ...)]
    [(sum-of-products ([a b] ...) #:extra extra)
     (+ extra (* a b) ...)]))
(sum-of-products ([2 2] [3 3]))
(sum-of-products ([2 2] [3 3]) #:extra 5)
```

See also [`syntax-parse`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Parsing_Syntax.html) for a utility that can make [parsing keywords](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Optional_Keyword_Arguments.html) easier.

Comment: In particular, the `syntax-parse` documentation has a whole [section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Optional_Keyword_Arguments.html) on writing macros with keyword arguments.